# Promise 'finally' callback equivalent in RxJS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a component that fetches some data from an API. The component has a `loading` member variable, which is used to determine whether a loading icon should be shown. When the data fetch completes, `loading` is set to false, in order to hide the loading icon. This should happen regardless of whether an error occurred or not.

Currently, I have implemented this as follows:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  loading = true;
  data;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.loading = false;
    },
    () => {
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }

}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to eliminate the duplication of `this.loading = false`. If I were using `Promises`, this is what I'd use the [`Promise.finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) callback for -- but I'm not. Is there an equivalent in RxJS, or a better way to implement this?

Comment: `finally` in RxJS 5.4 or `finalize` in RxJS 5.5 and onwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of RXJS 5.5, use the "finalize" operator:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getData()
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => this.loading = false)
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data;
  });
}
```